# Assign a public IP to a nested VM on GCP without using proxy or port forwarding

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-networking

I have a KVM instance deployed on GCP. There are nested VMs deployed on this KVM instance.
I would like to assign unique public IP addresses to these Nested VMs without the use of Proxies and port forwarding.

I was thinking of using alias IPs as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/enable-nested-virtualization-vm-instances#configuring_a_nested_vm_to_be_accessible_from_outside_the_host_vm)

I can then assign a unique alias IP to each of the Nested VMs and the nested VMs will now be in the same subnet as the hypervisor itself.

However I'm not sure how to assign a public IP address to these alias IPs. Is it possible?

Or is there a way to achieve the goal: `Assigning public IP to nested VMs`

Comment: I do not know the answer, but your question is very interesting. I read thru all of the documentation and I could not find anywhere where assigning an external IP is mentioned for an alias IP. Please update your post if you find a solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible today without some customization.  One possible workaround is documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/custom-public-ip-addresses-on-compute-engine).

Answer (score 0):

After several attempt to replicate this setup to see if it was possible, it does not appear to be so. Additionally, it is unlikely this kind of setup would be supported by Google even if you happen to get it working by some kind of customization, etc.

However, if there was a partial solution it would be around IP aliasing and/or bridging, like the [document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/enable-nested-virtualization-vm-instances#configuring_a_nested_vm_to_be_accessible_from_outside_the_host_vm) you attached.

I did also find this [community article](https://superuser.com/questions/1101100/how-to-bridge-networking-in-this-nested-virtualization-case) that may be helpful.